# How do I insert rows containing Timestamp values, using clojure.java.jdbc?

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, clojure

I'm trying to use clojure.java.jdbc to insert rows into a database.  (The database in question is sqlite).

I can create a table like this:

```
(def db {:classname "org.sqlite.JDBC"
         :subprotocol "sqlite"
         :subname "/path/to/my/database"})

(with-connection db (create-table :foo [:bar :int] 
                                       [:baz :int] 
                                       [:timestamp :datetime]))
```

And this works.  But if I try to insert a row into the database, this fails:

```
(with-connection db (insert-rows :foo
          [1 2 (java.sql.Timestamp. (.getTime (java.util.Date.)))]))
```

Giving an exception: assertion failure: param count (3) != value count (6).

But if I omit the timestamp field from the table definition and insert-rows operation, there isn't a problem.  So what am I doing wrong with the timestamp?

Answer (score 3):

```
 (def sqllite-settings
  {
   :classname   "org.sqlite.JDBC"
   :subprotocol "sqlite"
   :subname     "test.db"
  }
 )

(with-connection sqllite-settings 
  (create-table :foo 
        [:bar :int] 
        [:baz :int]  
        [:timestamp :datetime]))

(with-connection sqllite-settings (insert-rows :foo
       [1 2 (java.sql.Timestamp. (.getTime (java.util.Date.)))]))

(with-connection sqllite-settings 
       (with-query-results rs ["select * from foo"] (doall rs)))
```

returned the expected:

**({:bar 1, :baz 2, :timestamp 1311565709390})**

I am using clojure.contrib.sql

```
(use 'clojure.contrib.sql)
```

And the SQLLite driver from here: http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/

Can you try if contrib.sql works for you ?